# php how to do pagination problem?

Tags: php, pagination

i am trying to do some pagination for my website and i'm using [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/) and i run in a few problems.

first, this is how i find out the total nr of results:

```
$total_records_left = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id_fk` = 1';
$results_left = mysql_query($total_records_left) or die('Sorry, we could not count the number of results: ' . mysql_error());
$numberofresults_left = mysql_result($results_left, 0);
```

`$numberofresults_left` will return lets say `20 records`

now, if i fallow the tutorial, at one point i see that i need to declare this vars:

```
$pages = new Paginator;  
$pages->items_total = $num_rows[0];  
$pages->mid_range = 9;  
$pages->paginate();  
echo $pages->display_pages();
```

I don't understand how to connect my `$numberofresults_left` with those vars. How is the paginator.class.php is gonna know how many pages do i have?

also i see this query at one point: `SELECT title FROM comments WHERE title != '' ORDER BY title ASC $pages->limit` but there is no variable connected to it. Where i am gonna use this?

Please make me understand how this actually works
Thanks

Comment: I think `$numberofresults_left` should be called `$num_rows`.

Comment: where is `$num_rows[0]` coming from?

Comment: @ emaillenin,  i dont know, from the example

Comment: From the article, *The second line uses the query we did to get the total number of records and assigns it to our paginator's `items_total` property. `$num_rows` is an array containing the result of our count query (you could also use PHP's `mysql_num_rows` function to retrieve a similar count if you like).*

Comment: so i guess in my case `$pages->items_total = $num_rows[0];` should become `$pages->items_total = $numberofresults_left`

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a couple variables mixed up. `$numberofresults_left` looks as though it should be called `$num_rows`. As for the latter part of your question, `$pages` is the instance of the Paginator class, and `->limit` is the public property that records the limit when the object was created.

Towards the end of the article you're following, you should read the following:

> `$pages->limit` is critical in making everything work and allows our paginator
>   object to tell the query to fetch only the limited number of records that we
>   need. For example, if we wanted to see page seven of our data, and we're viewing
>   25 items per page, then `$pages->limit` would be the same as `LIMIT 150,25` in SQL.

Comment: well i tried to do `$total_records_right = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id_fk` = 2 ORDER BY com_name ASC $pages->limit';` but i get a syntax error.